UnsatisfiedDependencyException after building fat-jar with shadowJar
I have a SpringBoot Application using Vaadin and PostgreSQL that works fine when launching from the IDE (IntelliJ in my case).
Since I faced conflicts with exteral META-INF files, i stuck to this guide from Baeldung (Section 5) to create a fat jar using the shadowJar plugin.
The shadowJar buildtask finished successfully, created a jar of a reasonable size and spot-checking it, did not show any obvious flaws.
As I tried to run the jar, the application threw a quite well-known Exception in the Spring context:
15:52:08.661 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication -- Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'myService' defined in URL [jar:file:/home/shaese/myapp/build/libs/myapp-0.0.1-all.jar!/de/shaese/myapp/backend/services/MyService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'de.shaese.myapp.backend.services.MyRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:795)
    at [...]
    at de.shaese.myApp.Application.main(Application.java:16)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'de.shaese.myapp.backend.services.MyRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1880)
    at [...]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:782)
    ... 18 common frames omitted
[...]

If I am confident of one thing, than that I did not have forgotten any of the required annotations (like @Repository) or messed up with my own package structure (Application.java is at toplevel package and so is Application.class in the jar).
So my question is: Why do I get this particular Exception when trying to run my application from a jar?
A little bit of research unfortunately either leads to common issues causing the Exception in question (like this guide) or tutorials on how to build a jar with gradle. Neither of them seem to apply to my case.
Thanks in advance!

are you using "mvn clean package -Pproduction" to generate the jar?
